# Upload file using ng-file-upload and Spring Boot

Tags: java, angularjs, spring-boot, file-upload, ng-file-upload

I am trying to make a video upload using angular and spring boot. I am using [ng-file-upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload) in angular and in the controller I am using the following method to upload the file

```
   Upload.upload({
       url: 'api/uploadFile',
       data: {file: file, 'username': $scope.username}
   })
```

On the server I have declared my resource like this

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class FileUploadResource {

    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    @PostMapping("/uploadFile")
    public void uploadFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,  @RequestParam("username") String name)
```

When I try uploading the file I keep receiving a 500 error and I can't figure out how to solve it. If you could help me or if you could suggest another method that would be great

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Is the uploadFile controller method being called?  I'm guessing an exception is being thrown from the uploadFile method, in which case you should have a stack trace showing in your server log that will direct you to where the problem lies.

Comment: No, the method isn't called. I don't have a stack trace, I receive "error.internalServerError".

Answer (score 0):

Set headers in your upload to:

```
headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined }
```

It's better to send your data like this:

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("file", file);
formData.append("username", username);
```

And put `formData` as upload's data to send.